# I'm having trouble with the values which are returned by Console.ReadKey()

Tags: c#, console.readkey

Here's my original code, which I was trying to modify to limit data entry to a single `char`, converted to uppercase.

```
    public char promptForGuess()
    {
        Console.Write("\nGuess a letter: ");
        return Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
    }
```

I thought it would be easy:

```
    public char promptForGuess()
    {
        Console.Write("\nGuess a letter: ");
        return Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey().ToUpper());
    }
```

but I get this error:

`'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'ToUpper' and no extension method 'ToUpper' accepting a first argument of type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

which doesn't really mean a lot to me...and google wasn't terribly helpful either. I tried this,

```
    public char promptForGuess()
    {
        Console.Write("\nGuess a letter: ");
        return = Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

and got a message the I can't implicitly convert `ReadKey()` to `char`.

```
    public String promptForGuess()
    {
        Console.Write("\nGuess a letter: ");
        return Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

tells me that I can't implicitly convert `Console.ReadKey()` to `String`

So if it's not `char` and not `String`, what type is `Console.ReadKey()`. And how can I return a `char` with `ToUpper()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console.ReadKey() returns a [ConsoleKeyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.aspx). In the future you can answer these questions yourself by reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx). The page for ConsoleKeyInfo has a complete example of how to use it. The key bit is:

```
cki = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());
```

Comment: I saw that page...I didn't understand that ConsoleKeyInfo was the type. Now it makes a lot more sense! Thanks.

Comment: no problem. Knowing how to read the docs will make your life easier!